# Python TypeError for re.search in patterns

Tags: python, typeerror

You can view the complete file here: https://github.com/slideri812/pyhotn/blob/main/tapt.py
I wrote this about 6 months ago and it's been working great. I run this script with 2 others once a week every week. The other day after 950+ pages it hit an error: **TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**.

Over the past 5 days I have tried all kinds of ways to fix this but nothing works. I have reviewed many articles but it looks like everything I'm doing is OK. I thought it might be specific to that one page but can not find the problem or get it to move past the erroring page. I'm stuck.

Here is the complete error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
    159 
    160         for pattern in patterns:
--> 161             if re.search(pattern, text_to_search):
    162                 break
    163             else:

c:\users\slide\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\re.py in search(pattern, string, flags)
    197     """Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning
    198     a Match object, or None if no match was found."""
--> 199     return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
    200 
    201 def sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

The site adds and removes listings all the time, this has not been an issue. I have checked the page where it's throwing the error, the pages before it, and everything looks fine, though obviously it's not.
I have error handling built in as I expect there to be times when there is no data.

This bit fetches and data from the field(s):

```
    #location
    try:
        data_dict["location"] = detail.find("a",{"id":"myDataList_lblLocation_1"}).text.strip()[10:]
    except AttributeError as e:
        data_dict["location"] = None

    try:
        data_dict["location2"] = detail.find("span",{"id":"lblAddress"}).text.strip()
    except AttributeError as e:
        data_dict["location2"] = None
```

And here is my logic. I search the string for a city name and match that name to apply specific coding:

```
    #major
    patterns = ["Bangkok", "Phuket", "Chiang Mai", "Pattaya", "Chon Buri", "None"]
    text_to_search = (data_dict["location"])
    
    for pattern in patterns:
        if re.search(pattern, text_to_search):
            break
    
    if pattern == "Bangkok":
        data_dict["major locations"] = "54fbfc7f-a0cf-4a1d-9361-6059a44c2415"
    elif pattern == "Phuket":
        data_dict["major locations"] = "cbad67b4-7870-4ee2-b8a3-62d8c9f87091"
    elif pattern == "Chiang Mai":
        data_dict["major locations"] = "2966d83a-04f9-4b4e-b27e-05afe700b13f"
    elif pattern == "Pattaya":
        data_dict["major locations"] = "fbfaabca-0e9e-4db4-be1c-6cc8e8b8f63d"
    elif pattern == "Chon Buri":
        data_dict["major locations"] = "ce1da47b-78b6-4351-b849-e337db181c6a"
    elif pattern == "None":
        data_dict["major locations"] = "None"            
    else:
        data_dict["major locations"] = "No Match Found"
```

Some help would be much appreciated. I'm usually able to work these things out myself, often by reading and or trying different things, but not this time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like `data_dict["location"]` contains some lists or other non-string data.

Comment: Thank you. It was passing the None when no data was present and then not able to deal with that. I'm still pretty new to writing scripts. I thought it would just match the passed None to the None in the dict I'm searching against. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance, on line 120, you have this block:

```
try:
    data_dict["location"] = detail.find("a",{"id":"myDataList_lblLocation_1"}).text.strip()[10:]
except AttributeError as e:
    data_dict["location"] = None
```

My guess is that the you are encountering the attribute error and storing `None` as the value. Then when you go to regex search it later, you encounter the `TypeError`. Put a print or log statement in that except block to confirm

Comment: You are correct. I added print("location error") and changed  = None to  = "None". Now it loops through the loop starting at line 104 110 times exactly every time. BUT it then continues to the next url and keeps going. I run this script as a module and run 3 of them in sequence, then run a clean up script (pandas drop duplicates). Any insight into the looping? I've been working on it a couple hours with no success. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: There is an outer loop that starts on line 81, then the loop you are referring to on line 104. It makes sense that the outer loop would continue once the inner loop ends, I need a little bit more context though. You mention clean up with drop duplicates, is the loop is executing more times than it should?

Comment: Yes Mike that's correct. The loop at 104, when encountering No Data at line 123 for data_dict["location"] it loops 110 times for AttributeError & TypeError for that particular page. I have 2 excepts there now. At line 81 I set the list range: for url in linkext[953:957]: as the error kicks in at url 954, it will loop 110 times, every time, then moves to the next url. I've tried ending the try statement at line 123 with next and continue, neither makes a difference. You can try it yourself. Should I edit the post and add a screen cap? Thanks Again Mike

Comment: It might be worth making a new post as it is a little out of scope for the original question. I will clone your repo and try it myself later but am out of time tonight.

Comment: Mike you helped narrow the issue and I got it working and that's great!! I'm able to handle the extra duplicate entries for now. This script and it's 2 mates are all for learning python, how to write, how to trouble shoot, using modules and all of that. It's the first time I hit a wall that I just couldn't get around. So all of your help is much appreciated. BTW, I do my writing and testing in jupyter notebook. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the file on github. I commented out the old portions but left them for reference